# How to set permission in Facebook in application to upload photo?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, image-uploading, restfb

How to set the applications on facebook to be able to send a picture? I have access_token, APP_ID and secret_id but when you call in the application of this method:

```
FacebookType publishPhotoResponse = facebookClient.publish("me/photos", FacebookType.class,
      BinaryAttachment.with("albumID", bs),
      Parameter.with("message", "description"));
```

get this error:

```
com.restfb.exception.FacebookNetworkException: A network error occurred while trying to communicate with Facebook: Facebook request failed (HTTP status code null)
```

Could someone explain how to set it one by one on facebook application?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to ask for extended permissions, you can follow the [guide](http://pulkitgoyal.in/2013/01/09/requesting-extended-permissions-facebook-sdk-android/) here. From the post:

Let us first define what permissions we are going to need

```
// List of additional write permissions being requested
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_stream, publish_actions");

// Request code for reauthorization requests. 
private static final int REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE = 100; 

// Flag to represent if we are waiting for extended permissions
private boolean pendingAnnounce = false;
```

We will first check if we had all the required permissions. If not, we create a new ReauthorizeRequest with the set of permissions that we are requesting. This guides user outside our app to either the Facebook app or browser to confirm the permissions. When the user confirms the requests, he is redirected back to our application and onActivityResult for the Activity that invoked the reauthorization request is called.

```
private void handleAnnounce() {
    pendingAnnounce = false;
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session == null || !session.isOpened()) {
        return;
    }

    List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
    if (!permissions.containsAll(PERMISSIONS)) {
        pendingAnnounce = true; // Mark that we are currently waiting for confirmation of publish permissions 
        session.addCallback(this); 
        requestPublishPermissions(this, session, PERMISSIONS, REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE);
        return;
    }

    // TODO: Publish the post. You would need to implement this method to actually post something
    publishMessage();
}

void requestPublishPermissions(Activity activity, Session session, List<String> permissions,
    int requestCode) {
    if (session != null) {
        Session.ReauthorizeRequest reauthRequest = new Session.ReauthorizeRequest(activity, permissions)
            .setRequestCode(requestCode);
        session.reauthorizeForPublish(reauthRequest);
    }
}
```

This processes the result and calls the onSessionStateChanged if the session state changes. We then check in that method if our token was successfully updated and try to publish the message again.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE:
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null) {
            session.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
        break;
    }
}
protected void onSessionStateChange(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        if (state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) {
            // Session updated with new permissions
            // so try publishing once more.
            tokenUpdated();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Called when additional permission request is copmleted successfuly.
 */
private void tokenUpdated() {
    // Check if a publish action is in progress
    // awaiting a successful reauthorization
    if (pendingAnnounce) {
        // Publish the action
        handleAnnounce();
    }
}
```